# How not to remove other back-ends specific contents using org-org-export-to-org?

Tags: org-export

Using `org-org-export-to-org`:

```
#+ATTR_HTML: :style max-width:60%;
[[file:data/fool_f7dc.png]]
```

Is exported as:

```
[[file:data/fool_f7dc.png]]
```

Is there a way to keep the line `#+ATTR_HTML: :style max-width:60%;`?

Thx!

Edit:

Tried suggestion solution:

```
#+begin_export org
#+ATTR_HTML: :style max-width:60%;
[[file:data/fool_f7dc.png]]
#+end_export
```

But does not work since `org-org-export-to-org` returns:

```
#+BEGIN_export
[[file:data/fool_f7dc.png]]
#+END_export
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find out... does not matter anymore. 
Found a way out: https://github.com/phfrohring/org-to-blog/blob/master/org_to_blog.el

Answer (score 1):

An export block would be an option:

```
#+begin_export org
#+ATTR_HTML: :style max-width:60%;
[[file:data/fool_f7dc.png]]
#+end_export
```